# Codeigniter view undefined variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting the following error: Undefined variable: section in my home_view controller.
I've included line 17 in home_view.php and I'm pretty sure I'm passing all variables in correctly. Why is it giving me this error?

---

```
  <?php

    class Student extends CI_Controller  {


    function index()
          {
            $this->load->model('student_model');
            $data['section']= $this->student_model->browse_section();
            $this->load->view('home_view',$data);
          }

       }
```

### student_model.php

```
<?php

Class Student_Model extends CI_Model 
{

function browse_section() 
    {

    $q = $this->db->get('section');

        if($q->num_rows > 0 )
        {
        foreach ($q ->result() as $row )
                {
                $data[] = $row ;
                }
        }

        return $data;
    }

}
```

### Home_view.php

```
 <?php foreach($section as $r){
    echo '<h1>' . $r->Time . '</h1>' ; 
}
?>
```

Comment: in home_view controller? But you paste your student controller

Answer (score 2):

let me explain to you the error you are getting and correct it later on

lets start with the query on the model

```
<?php

Class Student_Model extends CI_Model 
{

function browse_section() 
    {

    $q = $this->db->get('section');

        if($q->num_rows > 0 )
        {
        foreach ($q ->result() as $row )
                {
                $data[] = $row ;
                }
        }

        return $data;
    }

}
```

clearly if the result set from the database is EMPTY then $data wouldn't be supplied with any value and the `function browse_section()` with the `return $data;` would be NULL in return to the controller and if passed to the view it will 100% create an Error because there's nothing to loop.

here are some suggestions to correct the issue 
1.) before assigning a return to a function make sure it has default value so assigning this line `$data = array(); on the first line in browse_section model function will do.` this will make sure that you return an empty Array that can be passed to the controller then on the view if no value is returned.
2.) I suggest you use result_array() for extracting Database records w/c has better use for array manipulation.

---

About the Controller nothing needs modifications.

__ 
About the view if you decided to use `result_array()` on the model you can change the foreach to but this is optional

```
 <?php foreach($section as $key => $value){
    echo '<h1>' . $value['Time'] . '</h1>' ; 
}
?>
```

but make sure to put

```
if(!is_null($section) && count($section) > 0) { 
//foreach here
}
```

this line will surely save you!

Happy Coding My friend!

Answer (score 1):

your `$data` variable is undefined. You need to define it before the if function in the model :

```
function browse_section() 
{

$q = $this->db->get('section');
$data = array(); //define the data array.

    if($q->num_rows > 0 )
    {
    foreach ($q ->result() as $row )
            {
            $data[] = $row ;
            }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: that does not solve the problem still saying it's undefined not sure why

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
$data['section']= $this->student_model->browse_section();
```

Not only you do not have `$data` defined, but also you do not have the key `section` defined. Please take a look at [the documentation of arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-87):

> **Note:**
>
> **Attempting to access an array key which has not been defined is the same as accessing any other undefined variable**: an E_NOTICE-level error message will be issued, and the result will be NULL.

I am not sure, what you are trying to achieve, but this may be enough to fix your code in `Student` controller:

```
$this->load->model('student_model');
$data = array();
$data['section']= $this->student_model->browse_section();
$this->load->view('home_view',$data);
```

To fix the part in the model, follow KDaker's tips.

Also read about what is undefined variable in PHP, and probably familiarize yourself with object-oriented programming. That will probably help you avoid similar and more important mistakes in the future.

Answer (score 0):

- That foreach loop in your model is not needed. Just return $q->result().
- num_rows is a method so your code should look like: $q->num_rows() instead of $q->num_rows
- Try to enable php display errors on your development environment which will help you fix these kind of bugs in a matter of minutes.

I hope these points help you further.